# How to do the marker management in google map

Tags: javascript

I have a large number of markers to show in the google map. so i want to do a clustering. I want to load  a particular number of markers for the  first time and when the bound will be changed the new new markers should show and the old should be deleted. below is the code i am using:

```
var addressArray = new Array("41 Green Ln, Handsworth, Birmingham, West Midlands B21")        
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
```

What will be code to load markers for a particular bound and the new markers will be loaded once we change the bound and the old will be deleted. i think we need to do a ajax call to get the new markers from db according to the new bound

Comment: Your question contains the answer. Yes, you would create markers only within given bounds but not query DB again and again. Create a data store object in javascript that resolves the addresses using geocoder and stores in an object/array and depending on the current location you query the markers from that object/array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  I think this is the general idea.  I presume you want mySQL/PHP.
I use markerclusterer.js, hosted by Google.
You will have to change the database connection values.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
  // for ajax call.  Returns markers within the bounds
  $north = $_GET['north'];
  $south = $_GET['south'];
  $west = $_GET['west'];
  $east = $_GET['east'];
  // You can see the bounds as just a rectangle, just give the max ans min values
  $sql = "
   SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude
   FROM city
   WHERE 
    latitude <= $north AND latitude >= $south AND
    longitude <= $east AND longitude >= $west 
  ";
  // I have a list of Belgian cities.
  $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); // Use your own connection values
  mysql_select_db('stackoverflow');
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $array = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $array[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($array);
  exit;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var timer;
  var markers = [];
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(50.5, 4.5);
  var options = {
    'zoom': 9,
    'center': center,
    'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    // we will trigger getMarkers(), but with a small delay.  
    // Only after the client stops panning/zooming for 1 second (feel free to change this value), we really trigger getMarkers.
    // this is a trick to do this
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(getMarkers, 1000);
  });
  // triggered by bounds_changed
  function getMarkers() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '?ajax=1',
      data: boundsRectangle(map.getBounds()),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // first clear the markers
        clearMarkers();
        // @see https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: data[i].name,
            map: map
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
    });
  }
  function clearMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
  }
}

// returns the min and max values of the boundsaries, so you get a box that contains at least the map boundaries 
// (notice: a projection of a rectangle looks less and less like a rectangle the gigger the bounds are)
//(I would not be surprised if there is a more elegant way to do this)
function boundsRectangle(bounds) {
  return {
    north: Math.max(bounds.Ea.j, bounds.Ea.k),
    south: Math.min(bounds.Ea.j, bounds.Ea.k),
    east: Math.max(bounds.va.j, bounds.va.k),
    west: Math.min(bounds.va.j, bounds.va.k)
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style>
#map-canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

A sample of the data; these are cities/municipalities in Belgium

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city (
  id bigint(15) NOT NULL,
  longitude decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  latitude decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
INSERT INTO city (id, name, longitude, latitude) VALUES
(14275, 'brussel', 4.3515499000, 50.8427501000),
(14279, 'schaarbeek', 4.3796600000, 50.8625502000),
(14280, 'etterbeek', 4.3969658000, 50.8332318000),
(14281, 'elsene', 4.3766927000, 50.8235717000),
(14282, 'sint-gillis', 4.3464309000, 50.8299126000),
(14283, 'anderlecht', 4.2986584000, 50.8238652000),
(14284, 'sint-jans-molenbeek', 4.3193694000, 50.8569755000),
(14285, 'koekelberg', 4.3250320000, 50.8632823000),
(14286, 'sint-agatha-berchem', 4.2925975000, 50.8657821000),
...
```